# Undefined is not a function while using react native firebase with expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

Recently I started React native development with Firebase but always get an error. The problem is I'm unable to use `import * as firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'`.

[image]

Comment: You should use proper formatting while adding code snippet to your questions so that it should be much clearer to the reader as well as avoid attaching screenshots of the code instead add the code snippet with proper formatting.